# How can I modify multiple filenames?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rename, mv

I am having these files in a folder:

```
1658286488_2022_07_21_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar 
1658546417_2022_07_22_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar 
2258286417_2022_07_23_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
```

and I want to standardize their names so they could look like this:

```
2022-07-21_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
2022-07-22_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
2022-07-23_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
```

I am looking for a simple command like mv, rename, or something along those lines, as I don't really like using complex bash scripts for this.

Comment: We don't know what counts as complex to you! I'd say: this is a job for a `for` loop in your shell, effectively three commands, can put them on one line. But you don't say what you've tried and where you met hardships (and honestly, `rename` might already be very close to what you need, what have you done with that?); would be pretty hard to give an answer that's less of a shell script than that, but then you will just end up not accepting the answer as "too complex a bash script".

Comment: i don't think this can be done with a simple command but a simple bash script can do this. To make things more easy you can  use 3 line python script.

Comment: I did rename -n -v  's/^(.{11})//' *.tar and now I only need to change _ to - in the date value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already tried using `rename`, here is a solution using `rename` (the Perl version of the utility that is part of the `p5-File-Rename` package on some systems):

```bash
rename -n -v -d 's/.*?_// && s/_/-/ && s/_/-/' *-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
```

The above command uses three substitutions:

1. The first substitution removes everything up to and including the first `_` character in the filename.  The Perl regular expression `.*?_` will match anything from the start of the filename up to the first underscore.
2. The second substitution changes the first `_` character in the modified filename into a `-`.
3. The third substitution is a repeat of the second substitution, which means that the next `_` character will be changed into `-` too.

The command will not do anything as it's invoked with the `-n` option, so remove that if you are sure it will do the right thing.

The `-d` option will ensure that only the filename portion of the path is renamed if you give full paths to your files in some other directory.  The `-v` option enables verbose operation.

If you have already successfully removed the first part of the filenames (as indicated by [one of your comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710527/how-can-i-modify-multiple-filenames#comment1345335_710527)), then simply remove the first substitution:

```bash
rename -n -v -d 's/_/-/ && s/_/-/' *-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! 
Just one more thing, it works if I am in current directory, but when I use absolute path for example: /home/devops/backups/**-ee_gitlab_backup.tar it says that the file or directory doesn't exist. Any clue on how rename works with paths?

Comment: I would guess that your `**` pattern matches a directory that includes a character (`_`) which is going to be remapped from `_` to `-`. You'll end up renaming the directory, and at that point none of the remaining files exists where it was supposed to

Comment: @Technosigma As roaima said, use `*` rather than `**`, and also add `-d` as I have now mentioned in my answer.  Your question says nothing about modifying filenames in any other directory than the current one, so I was not considering that the transformation could possibly match the directory path.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you so, so much!!! Have a great day!

Answer (score -1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/^[^_]*_(.*\.tar)/mv & \1/' <(find /path/to/dir -type f -name '*.tar' -printf '%f\n')
mv 1658286488_2022_07_21_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar 2022_07_21_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
mv 1658546417_2022_07_22_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar 2022_07_22_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
mv 2258286417_2022_07_23_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar 2022_07_23_15.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
```

If the renaming looks correct during the dry run, then you can commit the changes and execute the command.

```
$ sed -E 's/^[^_]*_(.*\.tar)/mv & \1/e' <(find /path/to/dir -type f -name '*.tar' -printf '%f\n')
```